# Show the existence of a number $\delta > 0$ and a diffeomorphism function $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $p(\varphi(x))=x^2$

Tags: analysis

Let $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ a polynom with $p(0)=p'(0)=0$ and $p''(0) > 0$. Show the existence of a number $\delta > 0$ and a diffeomorphism function $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $p(\varphi(x))=x^2$ for all $x \in (- \delta, \delta)$.

One polynomial that would satisfy the condition could be: $p(x)=x^2$. But how can I show the existence of $\delta$ and diff. function. ?

Comment: Doesn't $\varphi(x) = x$ do the job? The polynomial $p(x) = x^2$ also does fulfill the requirements.

Comment: @el_tenedor I just edited it!